# How to mix iota and values

Tags: go, enums, constants, iota

In a Go enum containing iota, how is it possible to force some values, yet auto-incrementing others?

For example, in this source code,

```
const (
    SUCCESS         int = iota
    ERROR_UNKNOWN       = 3
    ERROR_ARGS
    NOFILES             = 50
    ERROR_OPEN_FILE
    ERROR_BADFILENAME
)
```

`ERROR_ARGS`=`ERROR_UNKNOWN`, where I expected it to be `ERROR_UNKNOWN + 1` .

Is there a way to achieve mixing auto-increment and 'forcing' values, **without the `_` method**, that is cumbersome for big gaps like here (4 to 50, inserting 46 `_` lines...)

Clarifying after first answer below: Values must always 'go forwards', auto-incrementing even after a forced value.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://go.dev/play/p/zd-6bY6ID9w

Comment: @mkopriva Nice idea! Not ideally, because of the count that is not so automatic, but rather close to the goal.

Comment: IMO, don't do that. It will be very confusing to read that code for most people.  Either use iota for everything, or for nothing, if code readability means anything to you.

Comment: The marked duplicate shows examples to automatically calculate the offset. Easiest is to break the constant group, but you can also achieve automatic offset calculation in a single group if you add "sentinel" constant values used as offset in subsequent declarations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set `ERROR_ARGS = ERROR_UNKNOWN + 1` by iota, you can mix automatic increment with manual value like this:

```go
const (
    SUCCESS         int = iota
    ERROR_UNKNOWN       = 3
    ERROR_ARGS          = iota
    NOFILES             = 50
    ERROR_OPEN_FILE     = iota
    ERROR_BADFILENAME
)
```

Values will be:

```
0
3
2
50
4
5
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, too. But this is bad because some values 'go backwards' (50 -> 4)... The idea was to go always forward.

Comment: Edited the question to bold this. Sorry if it was not so clear.